# Unable to create graphs using highcharts-ng in meanjs. how to create graphs from the existing table in MEANJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts, meanjs

I have tried using highcharts-ng to create graphs in MEANJS but its not working. What is highcharts-ng's best alternative.

1.I have installed highcharts using

```
bower install highcharts-ng
```

2. Include it in applicationModuleVendorDependencies

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils','highcharts-ng'];
```

3.included in the assets lib

```
assets: {
    lib: {
        css: [
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
            'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css',
        ],
        js: [
            'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
            'public/lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js', 
            'public/lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js',
            'public/lib/angular-ui-utils/ui-utils.js',
            'public/lib/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
            'public/lib/highstock/js/highcharts.src.js',
            'public/lib/highcharts-ng/dist/highcharts-ng.js',
            'public/lib/file-saver/FileSaver.js'
        ]
```

4.put the following code in Index.htm

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl">
       <div class='container'>
                    <highchart id='example1' config='config'></highchart>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

5. and put the following code in the controller

   var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

   myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {

   ```
   $scope.config = {
       options: {
           chart: {
               type: 'column'
           },
       },
       xAxis: {
           categories: ['Yes', 'No']
       },
       series: [{
           name: 'Votes',
           data: [0, 0]
       }],
       title: {
           text: 'Data-binding Example'
       },
       subtitle: {
           text: 'Is this easy?'
       },
       credits: {
           enabled: false
       },
       loading: false
   };
   ```

The view shows no graph.Am I missing some thing?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you receive any errors in the console? Are you able to recreate it as live demo?

Comment: Make sure to also include highcharts (not just highcharts-ng)

Comment: Thank you sebastian and dylants, I am using google charts now.

Answer (score 0):

You must install oryginal highchart with comand:

```
bower install highcharts-release
```

and load it also with highchart-ng :

```
...
'public/lib/highcharts-release/adapters/standalone-framework.js',
'public/lib/highcharts-release/highcharts.js',
'public/lib/highcharts-ng/src/highcharts-ng.js',
...
```

and dont load twice highchart-ng when you declare module (only need to do in applicationModuleVendorDependencies):

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp');
```